# How to do a custom "grep" in linux terminal

Tags: command-line, grep

Suppose I have file which contains only a text like below:

> ```
> Test transition to drned-internal-asr9k-rt24711
>    load drned-internal-asr9k-rt24711
>    commit**
> ```

Now on the terminal if I do

> cat `filename` | grep load

I would get output something like

> load drned-internal-asr9k-rt24711

But how can I modify my grep command to get output as

> drned-internal-asr9k-rt24711.txt

i.e. remove "load " and add ".txt" at the end. So how to do that??

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be not the best solution but :

```
cat | grep load | cut -c4- | sed 's/$/.txt/'
```

`cut -c4-` will delete the 4 first characters

`sed 's/$/.txt/'` will add the ".txt" at the end of output

Comment: There is whitespace before `load` so you will need to delete more than 4 characters if you don't want this whitespace in the result.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the following:

```
sed -nr 's/.*load\s+(.*)/\1.txt/p' file.txt
```

This matches anything after `load` (plus one or more spaces) and returns it, adding `.txt` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(tolower($i)~/^load$/){print $(i+1) ".txt"}}}' file.txt
```

This matches next column after load and append .txt  to it in output.